# How to make a function print many times on the same line, e.g. print('test')*3

Tags: python, function

Let's say I have the code (although it doesn't do anything, just an example)

```
def myprint():
    print("foobar")
foo = random.randint(1, 6)
myprint() * foo    #Obviously doesn't work
```

What I want it to do is carry out `print()` 'foo' times. How do I do this?

Comment: Do note what ben w said: "*Note that your code contains a different error, which is that you're re-binding the name `print`.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your code to this one:

```
def myprint(times):
    print(times*"foobar")
foo = random.randint(1, 6)
myprint(foo)
```

Comment: ah, this must be what the OP actually wants. **user1247509:** if you accept this answer, please consider changing the title of your question to "How to make a function print something many times on the same line"

Answer (score 2):

The "pythonic" way is with a for-loop:

```
for n in range(foo):
    printfunc()
```

(Note that if you define print like you did in python 3, you're masking the original `print` with your own).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(foo):
    print('test')
```

If you really want to do it as an expression that returns something arbitrary (typically very bad, or at least extremely hackish, form)...

```
[print('test') for _ in range(foo)]
```

Comment: I think you should just delete the second part of your answer and pretend it never happened :)

Comment: @gnibbler: Probably, but at the time it seemed like the OP might be looking for it. Also this actually is a legitimate pattern when you want to do something like `[random() for _ in range(10)]`, since things like `[random()]*10` will not work as expected.

Comment: the difference is that in that example you are using the result of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to be obscure about it and annoy people reading your code:

```
import random
print('\n'.join(["foo" for _ in range(random.randint(1,6))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why you shouldn't call your own function `print`

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Dec  8 2011, 15:26:51) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help(print)

Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)

    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.


>>> def print():
...     print("foobar")
... 
>>> help(print)

Help on function print in module __main__:

print()


>>>
```

oops now you have overwritten the builtin `print` so you can't use it to actually print stuff anymore